# pyqt5 python: how to keep open dialog box when clicking "retry" button on same dialog

Tags: python, pyqt5, qmessagebox

Is there any way to keep the dialog box open once clicking one of the buttons to retry the IF statement that opens this box in first instance?
I want to continue clicking the "Retry" button once the condition is achieved without having this dialog box closed... otherwise, can you give me an idea how I can make this functionality?

```
import random
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox, QPushButton

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("My App")

        button = QPushButton("Press me for a dialog!")
        button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
        self.setCentralWidget(button)

    def button_clicked(self):
        self.rand = random.uniform(0, 1)
        print(self.rand)
        if self.rand > 0.5:
            self.critical = QMessageBox.critical(
            self,
            "Oh no!",
            "Something went very wrong.",
            buttons=QMessageBox.Retry | QMessageBox.Cancel,
            defaultButton=QMessageBox.Retry)
            if self.critical == QMessageBox.Retry:
                print("Retry!")
                self.rand = random.uniform(0, 1)
                print(self.rand)
            else:
                print("Cancel!")
        
        else:
            self.ok = QMessageBox(self)
            self.ok.setWindowTitle("All good!")
            self.ok.setText("Everything looks perfect!")
            self.button = self.ok.exec()
    
            if self.button == QMessageBox.Ok:
                print("OK!")
            

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec()
```

Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The static functions of QMessageBox automatically connect its buttons, so you only have two options: you either use a while loop and create a QMessageBox every time the value isn't valid and the reply button has been pressed, or you create a QMessageBox instance and disconnect its default signals.

### Basic while loop

This is the simplest solution: a while loop that continuously shows the message box until the value is valid; the drawback is that you cannot reuse the existing dialog, and a new one will always be shown;

```
    def button_clicked(self):
        self.rand = random.uniform(0, 1)
        print(self.rand)
        if self.rand > 0.5:
            while self.rand > 0.5:
                self.critical = QMessageBox.critical(
                self,
                "Oh no!",
                "Something went very wrong.",
                buttons=QMessageBox.Retry | QMessageBox.Cancel,
                defaultButton=QMessageBox.Retry)
                if self.critical == QMessageBox.Retry:
                    print("Retry!")
                    self.rand = random.uniform(0, 1)
                    print(self.rand)
                else:
                    print("Cancel!")
                    break
        # ...
```

### Using a QMessageBox instance

This is a bit more complex, but also more consistent. You need to create a new instance of QMessageBox, disconnect the `clicked` signal of its buttonbox (which is what QMessageBox uses to decide how to set its `finished` value), and instead connect its `accepted` and `rejected` signals; the latter will cancel the dialog, while the former will call a local function that generates a new value, and eventually accepts the dialog if it's valid:

```
    def button_clicked(self):
        self.rand = random.uniform(0, 1)
        if self.rand > 0.5:
            def checkRand():
                self.rand = random.uniform(0, 1)
                if self.rand > 0.5:
                    msgBox.accept()
                    print('OK!')
                else:
                    print(self.rand)

            msgBox = QMessageBox(
                QMessageBox.Critical, 
                "Oh no!", 
                "Something went very wrong.", 
                buttons=QMessageBox.Retry | QMessageBox.Cancel, 
                parent=self
                )
            buttonBox = msgBox.findChild(QDialogButtonBox)
            buttonBox.clicked.disconnect()
            buttonBox.rejected.connect(msgBox.reject)
            buttonBox.accepted.connect(checkRand)
            msgBox.exec_()
        # ...
```

Comment: Thanks so much @musicamante I tried the While option and works perfectly.
Highly appreciate it!